# Empty file keeps getting synced when I modify any file in a folder

Tags: 11.04, ubuntu-one, sync, libreoffice

I sync my `~/Documents` folder with u1 cloud. Once I modify any file in this folder, instead of a new version there is an empty file with the same name as document upload on the server.

And next time I log in, U1 tries to sync this empty file back to my `~/Documents` folder. As the result, I have an empty "name.odt" file and renamed to "name.odt.u1conflict" real document. Problem appears after I update to the 11.04.

Answer (score 1):

I also have this problem.
I have found a bug related to it: [LibreOffice u1conflict](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libreoffice/+bug/788788)

I suggest you click on the link to say that it affects you too. Together we have better chance to see this fixed!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, and have actually stopped syncing my odf files with U1 (I use dropbox for that now).

A possible "solution", would be to manually copy the files to U1 every time you update them. In 11.10 this will be easier as you can use Déjà Dup to do the work for you.